# sorting on C++ vector with cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, sorting, cython

I need a given structure with which i would have to do a lot of append/pop, accessing the values and make calculations.
I would have to do them continuously to update my data.

I first looked at python list that will be in a dic.
The main concern is that the calculations are slow, even a simple sum takes time.

I looked at the numpy side but the append/pop are long (although i don't think it's a good idea with numpy) and even accessing a value is not that fast.

I turned to cython to boost my code by staying on lists/dict and i saw a good performance gain but and it was always slow.

So i thought of turning to std::map and std::vector to do the same thing but faster.

I did the test with the sum of a vector, even numpy was slower so i thought i had found the structure i needed.
I then tested the sorting, which i should do very regularly and surprisingly the vector is 2-3 times longer than it takes to sort a list in python.
After a lot of research I can't figure out the reason why sorting vector was so 'slow'.

**test_cython.pyx**

```
# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort as stdsort

#I tried to import this way but the speed doesn't change.
"""cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    void sort(...)
    void stdsort "sort"(...)"""

cdef class VectorSort:
    cdef vector[long] v

    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(100000):
            self.v.push_back(i)

    def vector_sort(self):
        stdsort(self.v.begin(), self.v.end())

cdef class PythonSort:
    cdef list l

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [i for i in range(100000)]

    def python_sort(self):
        self.l.sort()
```

**main.py**

```
import timeit
from test_cython import VectorSort, PythonSort

v = VectorSort()
def sort_vector():
    v.vector_sort()

l = PythonSort()
def sort_python():
    l.python_sort()

print(timeit.timeit('sort_vector()', 'from __main__ import sort_vector', number=1000), '-> sort_vector')
print(timeit.timeit('sort_python()', 'from __main__ import sort_python', number=1000), '-> sort_python')
```

**output:**

```
0.9847416740085464 -> sort_vector
0.3762993350101169 -> sort_python
```

Comment: Python's sort will detect an already sorted vector and basically do one pass (see Timsort).  C++ sort may just be quicksort which doesn't have that.  I would try it with random or permuted numbers and see what you get.

Comment: @Max I tried with randoms numbers. Python is always 1.5-2x faster. The gap is already smaller but python is still the fastest.

Comment: OK but when you try with random numbers they're out of order the first time then in order the next 999 times you measure it. I can see the same results as you, but if I sort a __new copy__ each time then c++ becomes faster

Comment: Indeed I am stupid.
Can you tell me how much faster C++ was? I can't do the tests again until tomorrow.

Comment: @antho Just over twice as fast. The measurement isn't quite though because it's measuring copying+sorting. It's hard to avoid that though. Both cases look to be significantly slow if unsorted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this tomorrow